# Regex to allow only number between 1 to 12

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Regex to allow only number between 1 to 12

I am trying `(12)|[1-9]\d?` but its not working, please help as i am new to regular expression

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Something like

```
^([1-9]|1[012])$
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at start of the string
- `[1-9]` Matches `1` to `9`
- `|` Alternation, matches the previous match or the following match.
- `1[012]` Matches `10`, `11`, or `12`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dU5qB5/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response !!

Comment: Nice example!!, How could use this with a dynamic value, in the sense maybe it's 30 - 300 or 50 - 3500 etc

Comment: Probably it is better: `^(1[012]|[1-9])$` because so that if it isn't a double digit is for sure a single digit, whereas with the answer, it can find a digit of a double digit. In Python I noticed that for `10` it was returning `1` for example.

Answer (score 28):

Here's some readymade regex expressions for a bunch of different [numbers within a certain range](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s07.html):

| Range | Label | Regex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 to 12 | hour / month | `1[0-2]|[1-9]` |
| 1 to 24 | hour | `2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]` |
| 1 to 31 | day of month | `3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9]` |
| 1 to 53 | week of year | `5[0-3]|[1-4][0-9]|[1-9]` |
| 0 to 59 | min / sec | `[1-5]?[0-9]` |
| 0 to 100 | percentage | `100|[1-9]?[0-9]` |
| 0 to 127 | signed byte | `12[0-7]|1[01][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]` |
| 32 to 126 | ASCII codes | `12[0-6]|1[01][0-9]|[4-9][0-9]|3[2-9]` |

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
^(1[0-2]|[1-9])$
```

> 1[0-2] : first charcter must be 1 and second character can be in range
> from 0 to 2
>
> [1-9]     : numbers from 1-9
>
> ^        : start of string
>
> $      : end of string

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/ZkSB1FhIQK)

Answer (score 3):

[1-9]|1[012] works for greedy quantifiers (that try to match as much as they can) but will not match 10 for lazy quantifiers because as soon as it sees 1 it will stop.
[Try this at https://regex101.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGqyM.png)

[2-9]|1[012] will work with lazy quantifiers

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
\[1-9]|1[0-2]\
```

Comment: What are the backslashes for?