# Regex match cron expression

Tags: regex, cron

I want to extract the cron expression from a crontab line. 
I tried 2 regular expressions (pcre php):

```
^(.*?)(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

.. which works for `*/1 *   *   *   *   wget --spider ...`

and

```
^(.*?)(?=\/[a-zA-Z])
```

.. which works for `*/1 *   *   *   *   /my/path/ ...`

I also tried to combine both:

```
^(.*?)(?=\/[a-zA-Z])|(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

... but this catches the "wget" in sample 1, too. I dont want to match the exact expression `*/1    *   *   *   *`, this is just a sample. It must work for any cron expression.

Comment: Searching for "Regex match cron expression" returns so many results that it isn't even funny anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a regular expression for cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203122/how-to-create-a-regular-expression-for-cron)

Comment: The answers in the linked possible duplicate all don't seem to work for me, but I will take a closer look

Comment: @Tomalak: I totally disagree that your proposed search term, neither on stackoverflow nor on google, returns a lot of good results.

Answer (score -1):

After all I ended up with this imperfect but working solution:

`/((?<=^|\s)\*\/?\d*|(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=\s)|(?<=^|\s)\d+(?:\,\d+)+)/g`

I know it does not cover the complete crontab expression syntax. It will also match fragments that come later in the entry line, but I think usually there won't be any detached digits/asterisks. Correct me if I'm wrong.